wifi issue on ubuntu 22.04
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and my wifi gets disconnected after some time not following any regular time interval. But the problem is after getting disconnected every wifi available disappears from the available list and the only solution i found to these problem is to restart my pc and then i get available wifi networks list
